# Is it possible to change the color of a menu item on the appbar WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to change the color of a specific menu item on the appbar. Is this possible?

Comment: _Is this possible?_ Have you tried it first?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, you need to create your own appbar.